# Where are TLS certificates stored for Docker on Windows Server 2016 TP3

Tags: ssl, docker, windows-server

I have a VM running Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview, and have installed the Containers feature, and then run the Install-ContainerHost.ps1 script from Microsoft's container tools repo

https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-server-container-tools/Install-ContainerHost

I can now run the Docker Deamon on Windows. Next I want to copy the certificates to a client machine so that I can issue commands to the host remotely. But I don't know where the certificates are stored on the host.

In the script the path variable is set to %ProgramData%\docker\certs.d

Answer (score 3):

The certificates on windows are located in the .docker folder in the current user directory.

**docker --help** command will show the exact path details

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no certificates generated when you do what you are doing. If you drop certificates in the path you found then it will use them, and be secured. But otherwise there is none on the machine. Which explains why it isn't exposed by default.

On my setup I connected without TLS but that was on a VM that I could only access on my dev machine. Obviously anything able to be accessed over a network shouldn't do that.

Other people doing this are here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84ca60c0-c54d-4513-bc02-14bd57676621/connect-docker-client-to-windows-server-2016-container-engine?forum=windowscontainers and here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9caf90c9-81e8-4998-abe5-837fbfde03a8/can-i-connect-docker-from-remote-docker-client?forum=windowscontainers

When I dug into the work in progress post it has this:

> Docker clients unsecured by default
>
> In this pre-release, docker communication is public if you know where to look.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/work_in_progress#DockermanagementDockerclientsunsecuredbydefault

So eventually this should get better.